# Animate movement of div's with insertBefore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this structure of divs, like a slideshow:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slide str-1"><img></div>
    <div class="slide str-2"><img></div>
    <div class="slide str-3"><img></div>
    <div class="slide str-4"><img></div>
    <div class="slide str-5"><img></div>
</div>
```

Im using jQuery to switch the order of the divs every third second:

```
jQuery(".slide").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).insertBefore(jQuery(this).prev());
})
```

Im using CSS to create different sizes so the 1,2 and 4,5 images is smaller and behind the 5- and center image:

```
.slide {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s;
    &:nth-child(3) {
        transform:scale(1.6);
        z-index: 5;
    }
    &:nth-child(2),&:nth-child(4) {
        transform:scale(1.4);
        z-index: 4;
    }
}
```

Divs are switching places like I want, but the only problem is that there is no smooth transition. They just switch places like you would except them to do, which doesnt look to good.

Is there any way to animate this? Like so the image will smothly change size (scale) while switching position?

UPDATE: Fiddle with example of how it is now -> https://jsfiddle.net/3tfro9mb/6/

Comment: [`transition: 1s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) ?

Comment: Tried transition on `.slide`, but doesnt have any effect. Updated question with more of the CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little too fast here. You can't really animate insertBefore, because you create a new element which will be pushed to DOM. Best you can do with this approach is hiding those elements first and make them appear with `show('slow')`, or something like that.

Comment: if possible share your code in fiddler!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3tfro9mb/6/

Replaced the images with some colored divs. I want them to "slide" to the left while scaling down, but seems impossible with this code. Any other suggestions to how to solve it will be helpfull :)

Comment: Do you want to change the content of any .slide while running or does it stay the same - only changing the order? Or are you not interested in an appropriate answer to this question anymore - which I have in my toolbox...!

Comment: I solved this by using `position:absolute` instead. Not as clean, but it animates the movement of the divs.